# Pointer on vector of vector and iterator

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, iterator

I have a vector of vector of my object and I get a pointer of this vector. My problem is I can't create an iterator with that.
This my code :

```
vector<vector<AbstractBlock*>> *vectorMap = _level->getMap()->getVectorMap();

for(vector<AbstractBlock*>::iterator i = vectorMap[colonneX-1].begin(); i < vectorMap[colonneX-1].end(); i++)
{
    /*some operations*/
}
```

It failed on vectorMap[colonneX-1].begin(), if the vectorMap is not a pointer I can do this

How I can make this?

Thanks!

Comment: Because `vectorMap` is a pointer, `vectorMap[colonneX-1]` is not using `vector<>`'s `operator[]`, it's indexing into the pointer; try `(*vectorMap)[colonneX-1]`. Why are you using so many pointers in the first place anyway? Hideous...

Comment: I would suggest that you use more references and less pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dereference `vectorMap`:

```
for(vector<AbstractBlock*>::iterator i = (*vectorMap)[colonneX-1].begin();
    i != (*vectorMap)[colonneX-1].end(); i++)
```

Comment: Ah, yeah that's work great I had tried *(vectorMap) so that doesn't work

Comment: operator `[]` has higher precedence that `*`.

Answer (score 0):

vectorMap is a pointer to a vector, not a vector.  They are two different things.  The pointer simply refers to the vector, they are not one in the same.  You need to dereference vectorMap.

Answer (score 0):

You mistake the number of indirection. But there may be two different correct meaning.

if `vectormap` is a pointer, `vectormap[x]` is  the x-th `vectormap` in an hypothetical `vector<vector<AbstractBlock*>>` array.

I found strange that's what you mean, since it doesn't match the iterator type.

But `*vectormap` is a `vector<vector<...>>`, `(*vectormap)[x]` is a `vector<AbstractBlock*>>`, whose iterator, if dereferenced twice, is an `AbstractBlock`.

You most likely mean

```
for(vector<AbstractBlock*>::iterator i = (*vectorMap)[colonneX-1].begin();
    i != (*vectorMap)[colonneX-1].end(); i++)
    (**i).abstractblock_methodcall();
```